# high-DPI scaling -- 14.04 VM on OS 10.10 (PB 4), w/ Parallels 10.0.2

Tags: 14.04, display, macbook-pro, parallels

With this setup, the Ubuntu desktop still looks tiny on a 15" rMBP, just as it did with 12.04 and Parallels 8/9 on the same machine. I've tweaked the various Ubuntu settings, and enabled retina resolution in Parallels, but all to no effect. (I've also found no solutions in the many related posts.) Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks for any assistance.